# No sound from desktop's front headphone port

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio

My desktop has Windows 10 installed, and I decided I wanted to install Linux on the side and chose *Pop!_OS 21.04 (nvidia)*. But then I ran into the audio issue. The rear headphone port works fine and so does the monitor speakers. The only port that doesn't play sound is the front one. Everything works fine with Windows 10.

When I run `alsamixer`, it shows 4 cards:

- HDA Intel PCH
- Xtreme Audio DAC
- HDA Nvidia
- HDA Nvidia

However, when I select `HDA Intel PCH`, which seems to be the default, it says *"This sound device does not have any controls."* When I select the other cards, they all have settings for me to modify. None of them have anything relating to headphones and I don't see anything about *Auto-Mute* and nothing is muted. It doesn't matter where I have the headphones plugged in, and even if I don't, it never shows anything about headphones.

In the sound settings, when I have the headphones plugged into the front port, it says the *Output Device* is set to *"Headphones - Xtreme Audio DAC"*. When I plug the same headphones into the rear port, it says *"Speakers - Xtreme Audio DAC"* and gives me a drop down for Configuration with *"Analog Stereo Output"* selected by default.

I found many posts online and tried them all, but nothing ever worked. Modifying all the config files, using the *Pulse Audio Control* program, and following the article from *System76* about audio issues. I also installed the Ubuntu restricted extras, and VLC hoping maybe something was missing and this would install it, but nope.

I make sure all the volumes are at 100% when I shut down Windows (even using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Click on Shut Down option). I have also checked the BIOS and there are no sound options. I also have the boot option set to "UEFI".

First version I installed was *20.04 (nvidia version of course)* and had this issue. Then I tried *21.04 (nvidia)*, same thing. I got curious and installed *Ubuntu 21.04* (which I know isn't super different, but still wanted to try) but I still had the same issue.

So right now, I have Windows 10 installed on an SSD, and I have *Pop!_OS 21.04* installed on a separate hard drive. I have no clue what else to try. Has anyone encountered this before or have any suggestions for me to try? Thank you for reading.

These are my PC specs, just in case:

- MSI Z170A GAMING M9 ACK ATX LGA1151 Motherboard
- Intel Core i7-6700K 4.0GHz Quad-Core Processor
- Corsair Vengeance LPX 32GB (4 x 8GB) DDR4-2800 Memory
- Samsung 950 PRO 512GB M.2-2280 Solid State Drive (has Windows 10)
- Western Digital Black 6TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive
- Seagate 2TB 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive (has Pop!_OS 21.04)
- Asus GeForce GTX 980 Ti 6GB STRIX Video Card (2-Way SLI)
- Corsair 1000W 80+ Gold Certified Fully-Modular ATX Power Supply
- NZXT Kraken X61 106.1 CFM Liquid CPU Cooler
- NZXT Phantom 630 Windowed Edition (Black) ATX Full Tower Case